# Calling an instance variable from a class that is inside of that class

Tags: python, class

I have a class that has a logger instance variable, and I am creating another class inside of that and I want to use the logger instance variable inside of that class, but not sure how to call it.

Example Code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger.get() #this works fine didn't include the Logger class

    def func(self):
        class B():
            def __init__(self):
                self.a = 'hello'
            def log(self):
            #How do I call A's logger to log B's self.a
            #I tried self.logger, but that looks inside of the B Class
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Zen of Python states, *"Flat is better than nested."* You could un-nest `B`, and pass the logger as an argument to `B.__init__`.
By doing so,

- You make clear what variables `B` depends on.
- `B` becomes easier to unit test
- `B` may be reused in other situations.

---

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger.get() #this works fine didn't include the Logger class

    def log(self):
        b = B(self.logger)

class B():
    def __init__(self, logger):  # pass the logger when instantiating B
        self.a = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 5):

The name `self` isn't a language requirement, it's merely a convention. You can use a different variable name like `a_self` so the outer variable isn't masked.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = Logger.get() #this works fine didn't include the Logger class

    def func(a_self):
        class B():
            def __init__(self):
                self.a = 'hello'
            def log(self):
                a_self.logger.log('...')
```